# Use commas to join expression components

Tags: python-2.7

- trafficLightsCount =12
- bufferDist = '5 mi. '
- intersectionCount = 20
- print 'Found',  trafficLightCount, light in
  the intersectionCount, buffer and, 'buffereDist 'intersections.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a='something'
b=12
c='Another thing'
print 'Found : ' + '{0},{1},{2}'.format(a,b,c)
```

You will get the output : `Found : something,12,Another thing`